# How to sum inAngular?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.homeService.readPolicies(19).subscribe((policies: Fee[]) => {
      this.fee = policies;
      console.log(this.fee);
      this.homeService.readStudent(+this.fee[0].studentId).subscribe((student: Student) => {
        this.studentfee = student;
        console.log(this.studentfee[0].fee);
        this.studentfee = this.studentfee[0].fee;
      });

});
```

How Can I do sum of all elements?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried till now? It seems like a simple addition operation as already you are iterating over each student.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't subscribe within a subscription! Use switchMap. And when you subscribe don't forget to unsubscribe.

You can sum Array Values with lodash easily.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'
_.sumBy(policies, 'fees');
```

(see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Observable` as it seems from your code,

you can use `.pipe` to `map` only the student fees and then `reduce` to get the sum.

[see working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxskyc)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';

//moking a smaleer version of your data for the example
const STUDENTS = [
    {fees: '30', id: '10'},
    {fees: '20', id: '10'},
    {fees: '11', id: '10'},
    {fees: '321', id: '10'}
  ];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  studentfee: number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {

    /**
     * The example
     */
    from(STUDENTS)
      .pipe(
        map(student => parseFloat(student.fees)),
        reduce((sf, val) => sf + val)
      ).subscribe((sum: number) => {
        this.studentfee = sum;
      });

    /**
     * Your codes should look more like this..
     */

    // this.homeService.readPolicies(19).subscribe((policies: Fee[]) => {
    //   this.fee = policies;
    //   console.log(this.fee);
    //   this.homeService.readStudent(+this.fee[0].studentId)
    //     .pipe(
    //       map(student => parseFloat(student.fees)),
    //       reduce((sf, val) => sf + val)
    //     ).subscribe((sum: number) => {
    //       this.studentfee = sum;
    //     });

    // });



  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [custom sum pipe example in stackblits.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sum-pipe-module).

```
<span>{{ studentArray | sum:'fees' }}</span>
```